# Cannot install any OS on my pi 3 using noobs lite and cant boot from any OS image

Tags: pi-3

I have just the noobs lite on my sd card, put in pi, power up pi, see the noobs window that gives the OS options to install. When I choose any OS and click install it begins then stops with the error shown. I have also tried to install the raspbian OS full image to sd card but when I insert it to the pi and power up it does not boot.
Does anyone know what is going on here and how I can fix it.[image]

Comment: Welcome, but you will have to clarify the context: 1) How are you trying to install the image?  2) Exactly when and where does this error occur?  On the Pi or ...?

Comment: My apologies, so I have just the noobs lite on my sd card, put in pi, power up pi, see the noobs window that gives the OS options to install. When I choose any OS and click install it begins then stops with the error shown. I have also tried to install the raspbian OS full image to sd card but when I insert it to the pi and power up it does not boot.

Comment: There are many, many, many questions here that are a variation on this theme.  I'm afraid there is not much anyone can say to you besides put a fresh image on the card following [the official instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/software-guide/quickstart/).